# I am using Jenkins ver. 1.640, and when I try to launch slave then i got this error

Tags: jenkins

I am using ssh key pairs for launching the slaves.Someslaves are working fine. but someslaves when I try to "relaunch slave agent", then i got this error as below. OS :- Ubuntu 14.04LTS ,java version "1.7.0_65" on slave machine and on jenkins server machine java version "1.7.0_85".
[image]

```
    Expanded the channel window size to 4MB
    [01/22/16 07:41:12] [SSH] Starting slave process: cd "/home/tmp" && java  -jar slave.jar

    <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started

    Slave.jar version: 2.53.2

    This is a Unix slave

    Evacuated stdout

    Connection terminated
    ERROR: Failed to install restarter
    hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
        at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:297)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:847)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1080)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:501)
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:60)
        at ......remote call to Mbox_19(Native Method)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
        at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:780)
        at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.install(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:52)
        at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.access$000(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:33)
        at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller$1.call(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:39)
        at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller$1.call(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:36)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    ERROR: Unexpected error in launching a slave. This is probably a bug in Jenkins.
    Caused by: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1080)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:501)
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:60)
    Caused by: Command close created at
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem and was able to fix it by re-downloading the slave.jar from the Jenkins master. Apparently during an upgrade something about the interface between master and slave had changed. You may want to try 're-installing' your slave configuration by re-downloading and updating your secret.

Comment: I tried but it's not working still, Thanks @EliRibble